# Optimize queries with eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working with laravel and eloquent for this I have a model called Expense that refers to a simple table that has more or less this structure:

```
|  expenses  | 
|------------|
| id         | 
| date       | 
| amount     |
| created_at |
| updated_at |
| deleted_at |
```

Now I need to get the total expenses for each month of the current year, so do the following:

```
Expense::select( DB::raw('sum(amount) as sums'), 
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as months"))
         ->groupBy('months')
         ->get();
```

The previous code generates the following query:

```
select sum(amount) as sums, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as months from `expenses` where `expenses`.`deleted_at` is null group by `months`
```

This works, but my problem with this is that I have many records in my table, and the query performs a full scan, how could I improve my code and optimize my query?

Comment: are amount and created_at indexed?

Comment: Your SQL is quite simple and IMO, there is not much change that you could make to improve the performance. How did you index your table?

Comment: I tried indexing `created_at` but without major changes. apparently when grouping them then all this is wasted

Comment: is `MONTH(created_at)` any different?

Comment: there is no difference, reviewing the execution plan of the query this continues to run the entire table